# Localization with String interpolation in SwiftUI

Tags: localization, swiftui

I am trying to localize my SwiftUI Watch app.
I don't have any problems with static strings. I use LocalizedKeyStrings in my Text views and add my translations in Localizable.strings files.
For example:

```
Text("history")
```

in Localizable.strings:

```
"history" = "Historique";
```

Result : 
"Historique"

But I also want to localize stings using interpolation. For example:

```
Text("startCustom \(format: "%.1f",customDistance)")
```

In Localizable.strings, I have tried with different syntax:

```
"startCustom %@" = "Course de %@ km";
```

or

```
"startCustom %f" = "Course de %f km";
```

or

```
"startCustom %.1f" = "Course de %.1f km";
```

Nothing works.
I don't find any documentation for that ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following simple just works (tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("startCustom %.1f", comment: ""), 
     self.customDistance))
```

with Localizable.string having

```
"startCustom %.1f" = "Course de %.1f km";
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, thanks, but I still have a bug: it displays the text in English instead French when I use the "fr" localization. All the other translations are right, but this one seems to only use the English Localizable.strings

Comment: You can forget my last comment. It's a bug only with Xcode and/or simulator. It works well on the real device. Thanks for you easy and helpful solution !!

Comment: when using this approach, after applying translation app renders the text in this format: "Course de ("15.5") km" any ideas why?

Answer (score 35):

Apparently, a `LocalizedStringKey` will automatically generate the localization key depending on the type of the values interpolated. For example, if you have the following `Text`s

```
Text("title key")
Text("name key \("Club")")
Text("count key \(8)")
Text("price key \(6.25)")
```

Your Localizable.strings file should look like

```
"title key" = "Sandwiches";
"name key %@" = "Name: %@";
"count key %lld" = "%lld sandwiches";

// You can change the format specifier in the value, but not in the key.
"price key %lf" = "Price: %.2lf";
```

Be careful if you want to support 32-bit systems (iPhone 5 or earlier). In a 32-bit system, `Int` is `Int32`, the key of `"int32 key \(Int32(8))"` is `"int32 key %d"`. You can always convert an integer to `Int64` like in `"count key \(Int64(8))"` to enforce consistent keys across different systems.

Remark 1: For people who want to know how it works. When you use a string literal or an interpolated string such as `"count key \(8)"` in `Text`, the compiler will consider the string as a `LocalizedStringKey`, because `Text` has an initializer

```
init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil),
```

and `LocalizedStringKey` conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` and `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` and thus can be implicitly initialized from a string literal or a string interpolation.

Remark 2: If you're not sure what the key is, you can get the answer yourself by po a LocalizedStringKey in the debugger like this:

```
po LocalizedStringKey("count key \(8)")
```

Comment: Excellent answer. In case anyone else is having problems, I finally discovered with Xcode 12.0.1 that the SwiftUI  iOS 14 previews DO NOT work with localizations of strings with variables, e.g. Text("count key \(x)") but the same localizations DO work correctly when run on the simulator or device.  So don't trust the previews.

Comment: @arcdale I found preview sometimes works sometimes doesn't, maybe a bug.

Comment: Your advice to use the debugger to find the correct format is genius! Solved my issue.

Comment: Other string format specifiers: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Had to use %lld for integer tho. Took some time till figured it out

Answer (score 7):

**My way**

Localizable file

```
"myNameIs %@" = "My name is %@.";
```

SwiftUI file

```
struct TestLocalize: View {
        
    var name = "Hien Nguyen"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("myNameIs \(name)")
    }
}
```

**Result**

My name is Hien Nguyen

Comment: Thanks! Your variant worked with Images in `Localizable.strings`.