# SwiftUI - LocalizedStringKey interpolation

Tags: swiftui, string-interpolation, localizedstringkey

I have a Localizable.strings with all the text I need. Example:

`"Welcome": "Hello there, welcome!!";`

To not misspeal the LocalizedStringKey "Welcome" in many parts of the app I created an enum like this:

```
enum LocalizableKey: LocalizedStringKey {

    case welcome = "Welcome"
    case interpolationCase = "Interpolation case %@ etc etc"
}
```

In SwiftUI it works if I use `Text(LocalizableKey.welcome.rawValue)`.

My question is how can I interpolate a string for the case of .interpolationCase where I want to add a parameter?

`Text(LocalizableKey.interpolationCase.rawValue)` <- Add a parameter. Also is it possible to add an attributedString for the parameter to have a different color?

Let's discard the solution of separating the text like this:
`Text(LocalizableKey.interpolationCase.rawValue)` + `Text(\(parameterValue))` + `Text(LocalizableKey.anothercase.rawValue)`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042837/12299030?

Comment: No because in NSLocalizedString( X , comment: ""), X is expecting a String not a LocalizableStringKey.